# How to use mex service in WCF that requires user name authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, mex

I've created a TCP based web service than exposes a mex endpoint. Recently, I've added user authentication through

```
        var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, true);
        tcpbinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new BWUserNamePasswordValidator();
        svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode =UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
        svh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = TcpBindingCertificate;
```

Now, when I'm trying to update the service reference in the client project, I'm getting an error message about metadata containing reference that can't be resolved. When the security code is removed, the mex works fine

Here's the code for the mex endpoint:

```
        // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = svh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        // If not, add one
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        //smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        svh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Add MEX endpoint
        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
          ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
          MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
          location+"/mex"
        );
```

Why am I getting this, and how can this be fixed?